# Users of digital images in high volumes?

Tags: image, digital

Really appreciate if you can help me out finding what businesses (NON Medical) may use digital imaging in high volumes?

I am working on a medical DICOM imaging project but want to look around to see other applicaitons for medical images acquired and stored in good numbers for any purpuses.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

GIS-based companies might work with large satellite images.

Material science companies might work with large microscopy images.

Comment: The material science companies sound very interesting.  They totally escaped my mind :-).  Do you have an example of such organizations?  Thank you very much for the quick response.